# Has anybody created a job with multiple inputs using the the ruby client for Amazon's Elastic Map Reduce?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, elastic-map-reduce

Through the UI Amazon's framework allows me to create jobs with multiple inputs by specifying multiple --input lines. e.g.:

-input s3n://something -input s3n://something-else

Similarly the Ruby EMR client has been very helpful to me so far:
http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/2264

However, I'm trying to script a nightly job that requires multiple inputs and I can't seem to find any way to do this. It won't let me pass multiple -input parameters and when I use --arg or --args the job that is created does not contain the -input lines. It is almost as if it is stripping it out.

Has anybody used this tool for this purpose successfully?

Answer (score 5):

Turns out you do use --args but it has to follow the --stream or --bootstrap-action options. It can't be tacked on to the end of the commandline:

http://www.henrycipolla.com/blog/2011/09/how-to-create-an-emr-job-with-multiple-inputs-using-the-ruby-client/

--Henry